# How to Modify and Combine rows in an attribute table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, enterprise-geodatabase, sql, python-parser

I would like to modify this attribute table.

This is an example

- First arrange column “ORG_FID” in ascending order
- If the number of rows corresponding to the column “block Number” is same as well as “Lot Number”, then as per the column “ORIG_FID”, I want to add additional column as “ Combinetxt” and the combine text will arrange as per the “ORIG_FID” ascending order “N/F ONIS B. PUPO AND ALEIDA  M. PUPO, H/W” for both the rows.
- Then I can dissolve the attribute table  on the basis on 3 columns. (“Block Number”, “Lot Number”, “Combinetxt”)
  [image]

Answer (score 2):

I would direct you to utilize [Calculate Field examples](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm#GUID-9E423208-C918-442C-8D68-03AFB6C28709)

> Entering values with the keyboard is not the only way you can edit values in a table. In some cases, you might want to perform a mathematical calculation to set a field value for a single record or even all records.
>
> You can perform simple as well as advanced calculations on all or selected records. In addition, you can calculate area, length, perimeter, and other geometric properties on fields in attribute tables. The sections below include examples of using the field calculator. Calculations can be performed using either Python or VBScript.
>
> Python is the recommended scripting language for ArcGIS. Use Python if you want access to geoprocessing functionality, including feature geometry. The adoption of Python as the scripting language for ArcGIS provides many opportunities for performing calculations.

A related script: this is just a general example would be to incorporate some sort of logi

> Parser:
> Python

Expression:
Reclass(!WELL_YIELD!)

```
def Reclass(WellYield):
if (WellYield >= 0 and WellYield <= 10):
    return 1
elif (WellYield > 10 and WellYield <= 20):
    return 2
elif (WellYield > 20 and WellYield <= 30):
    return 3
elif (WellYield > 30):
    return 4
```

[Field Calculator PDF](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0405/files/fieldcalc_1.pdf)